# Ifelse function based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a new column (TRUE/FALSE) based on the values of three other columns (also TRUE/FALSE).
This is a small sample.

```
DF
ID     1      2      3
1      TRUE   NA     NA
2      FALSE  TRUE   NA
3      TRUE   TRUE   NA
4      TRUE   FALSE  NA
5      TRUE   FALSE  TRUE
6      FALSE  FALSE  TRUE
7      TRUE   FALSE  FALSE
8      FALSE  NA     NA
9      NA     NA     NA
```

Not all three columns have the same amount of rows. (therefor a lot of NA values). The data were files that were checked and in column 2 some of them were re-checked and in column 3 an even smaller portion was again re-checked.

So Column 2 overrides column 1, and column 3 overrides column 1 and 2.

I would like the following output

```
ID     1      2      3           4
1      TRUE   NA     NA          TRUE
2      FALSE  TRUE   NA          TRUE
3      TRUE   TRUE   NA          TRUE
4      TRUE   FALSE  NA          FALSE
5      TRUE   FALSE  TRUE        TRUE
6      FALSE  FALSE  TRUE        TRUE
7      TRUE   FALSE  FALSE       FALSE
8      FALSE  NA     NA          FALSE
9      NA     NA     NA          FALSE
```

Classes are character so ive tried it with the function ifelse and grepl

```
DF$4 = ifelse(
        grepl("TRUE", DF$1) |
                grepl("TRUE", DF$2 |
                grepl("TRUE", DF$3), "TRUE","FALSE"  ))
```

But this only allows me to give certain conditions for the option TRUE. I dont know how to implement if column 2 shows FALSE en column 1 shows TRUE to get the output FALSE.

I've tried to search stackoverflow for a similar question/answer, (there probably is) but i couldnt find it therefor i would like to ask it here.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the last non-NA values for each rows:

```r
df$v4 <- apply(df[, -1], 1, FUN = \(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), FALSE, unlist(tail(x[!is.na(x)], 1))))

#> df$v4
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

<sub>Note: `\` can replace `function` in lambda-like functions since R 4.1.</sub>

Comment: Thank you Mael! Your code works! However i have an other column in this dataset which contains id numbers (stupid of me to not include this in the question, i thought maybe it was irrelevant). When this column is included (it's the first), the code changes all values for df$v4 to the id numbers. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: You can select your columns; for instance, setting -1 will remove the first column, see my answer.